# Setting Cursor-Color in GTK+ 3

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm looking to set a GtkTextView cursor-color. I know I can do it through the [gtk_rc_parse](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Resource-Files.html) command or something similar, but the documentation says that those commands are depreciated, and I don't think [GtkCssProvider](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) supports cursor-color. Is it possible to set it some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-cursor

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in gtk3 with CSS. GtkTextView itself doesn't have a "cursor-color" property. You must go up in hierarchy to GtkWidget which does have that property and since GtkTextView is a type of GtkWidget you can style the GtkTextView through GtkWidget. So you use:   -GtkWidget-cursor-color

This is true for other properties as well. For instance, "focus-line-width". This property is shared by several widgets including GtkButton and the rows of a GtkTreeView.
The style property listed for a specific widget in the documentation must be preceded by: -widgetname-

For instance, the only style property listed for GtkTextView is "error-underline-color" So in the CSS you would use: -GtkTextView-error-underline-color

Here's an example of changing "cursor-color" and other properties in a GtkTextView:

[http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=988&p=195276=Styling+a+GtkTextView+with+Gtk3+and+Css%3A#p195276](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=988&p=195276=Styling%20a%20GtkTextView%20with%20Gtk3%20and%20Css%3a#p195276)

Comment: Site no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there seem to be cursor-color style property:
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--s-cursor-color

Comment: Since GTK 3.20 this has been replaced with the "caret-color" property. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--s-cursor-color